# JSF ViewScoped бин не использует мой экземпляр

Tags: java, jsf

Здравствуйте!

Я создаю объект бина в главном бине `MyPostsBean` и добавляю его в `ViewMap` таким образом:

```
    Category_MY_POSTS bean = (Category_MY_POSTS) EnumBusinessCategories.getCategoryClass(EnumPackageCategories.MYPOSTS.name(), category);
    CommonUtils.addToView(EnumBusinessCategories.getBeanName(EnumPackageCategories.MYPOSTS.name(), category), bean);
```

Далее, получаю этот объект и выполняю запрос:

```
    Category_MY_POSTS bean = (Category_MY_POSTS) CommonUtils.getFromView(EnumBusinessCategories.getBeanName(EnumPackageCategories.MYPOSTS.name(), category));
    bean.selectList_userPosted();
```

Запрос выполняется и устанавливается поле бина `offersList`. Бин наследуется от POJO класса, в котором объявлен этот список.

Проблема в том, что в XHTML метод `myOffers.offersList` не возвращает мне ранее присвоенный список `offerList`. Я пробовал отлаживать и обнаружил, что хэш бина во время присваивания списка отличается от хэша во время его извлечения.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myPostsBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyPostsBean extends MyPostsPOJO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1573342923390687013L;

    public MyPostsBean() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ...
        String currentCategory = (String) CommonUtils.getRequestValue("category");
        if(CommonUtils.getSessionValue(BundleConstants.USERID)!=null){
            selectList_userPosted(currentCategory);
        }
        ...
    }
}

@ManagedBean(name="myOffers")
@ViewScoped
public class OfferBean extends OfferPOJO implements Category_MY_POSTS, Serializable {

    @Override
    public String selectList_userPosted() throws IOException {
        offersList = OfferBO.getInstance().selectList_userPosted();
        return "";
    }
}

public class OfferPOJO extends CommonPOJO {

    protected List<Map<String, Object>> offersList = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getOffersList() {
        return offersList;
    }
}
```

Comment: что происходит между bean.selectList_userPosted() и myOffers.offersList, не происходит ли GET запросов?

Comment: В общем, была банальная опечатка. Бин имел имя myOffers, в то время как в viewMap ложился бин с именем mypostsOffers. Обноружил когда пытался создать проект пример с упомянутыми классами.